# Add click to imagebutton inside gridview dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, imagebutton

I tried to fire the event click for an ImageButton from the footer of a gridview but I it didn't fire, 
I will appreciate any help, 
thanks in advance, 
here is the code

```
protected void grvBubDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
         ImageButton imgbtnSendMail = new ImageButton();
         //ImageButton imgEdit = new ImageButton();
         imgbtnSendMail.ImageUrl = "~/Images/mail01.png";
         imgbtnSendMail.AlternateText = "Edit";
         imgbtnSendMail.ToolTip = "for send mail press here";
         imgbtnSendMail.Width = imgbtnSendMail.Height = 20;
         //imgbtnSendMail.CommandName = "sendMail";
         //imgbtnSendMail.CommandArgument = "somevalue";
         imgbtnSendMail.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imgbtnSendMail_Click);
         //imgbtnSendMail.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
         //imgbtnSendMail.Attributes["onclick"] = "imgbtnSendMail_Click";
         e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Add(imgbtnSendMail);
    }
}
protected void imgbtnSendMail_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
        string Text = "Image clicked";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update grvBubDetails_RowDataBound event like this;

```
ImageButton imgbtnSendMail = new ImageButton();
imgbtnSendMail.CommadName = "cmdSendMail"; // add this line
imgbtnSendMail.CommadArgument = "also you can pass a parameter from here";
```

Add RowCommand event to grid view. Do this in RowCommand event handler function;

```
if(e.CommandName.equals("cmdSendMail")){
    string Text = "Image clicked";
    string argument = e.CommandArgument;
}
```

Update:

Grid view's RowCommand event fired after PageLoad event. Your button removed after every page reload, and has not recreated because rowDatabound event does not fire.

working code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>()
            {
                "item 1",
                "item 2",
                "item 3"
            };
            GridView1.DataSource = list;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        // make sure outside of !IsPostback
        // recreate button every page load
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.CommandName = "cmdSendMail";
        btn.CommandArgument = "sample arg";
        btn.Text = "send mail";
        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[0].Controls.Add(btn);
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(e.CommandName + new Random().Next().ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried this, but it doesn't go inside grvBubDetails_RowCommand !!! Is that because it is a footer??

Comment: I did similar code before with a Button but with ImageButton I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: Is EnableViewState true for page and grid view control? If you have databindig code in page load event, make sure it is in if(!IsPostBack) block.

Comment: yes it is true, and I make bound for the grid inside if(!IsPostBack) block

Comment: Try adding same button inside Datarow. i am currently on a mac computer and i can not run .net code ...

Comment: I know that I annoyed you, but really I appreciate you help, I'll try my best and if you found any solution, I appreciate that

Comment: Thank you very much, I have just seen your answer, and tried it, it works fine, sorry for being late, I took a leave for two days :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the `ImageButton` on global scope (class level)

```
ImageButton imgbtnSendMail = new ImageButton();
protected void grvBubDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
     {
```